# VC++ 17 internal compiler error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have some really weirdly behaving code which makes the compiler crash. I am using VC++ 17:

```
//.hpp
typedef unsigned short UID;
typedef UID GoodType;
typedef struct _Recipe
{
    typedef struct {
        GoodType goodType; unsigned short units;
    } GoodRatio;
    std::vector<GoodRatio> input;
    GoodRatio output;
    //int a;
} Recipe;

//.cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<Recipe> recipes
    {
        {
            { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 } }, { 2, 1 }
        },
    };
}
```

The error:

```
1>c:\users\peter\downloads\nationsgamemockup\nationsgamemockup\nationsgamemockup.cpp(25): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 255)
1> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
```

The behaviour I observed so far:

If I uncomment the `//int a;` line the error goes away regardless of whether I add an argument for a in the constructor call in the main function.

If I comment the `std::vector<GoodRatio> input;` line and remove the corresponding argument from the constructor call the error goes away.

If I comment the `GoodRatio output;` line and remove the corresponding argument from the constructor call the error goes away.

If I change the `recipes` variable in `main` to just a single `recipe` the error goes away (as in simply `Recipe a{ { { 0, 1 },{ 1, 2 } },{ 2, 1 } };`).

**Note:**
The `_Recipe` struct cannot be an anonymous struct because it has a data member of type `std::vector<GoodRatio>` and the `Recipe::GoodRatio` type only comes into existence at the semicolon after the typedef. That is my guess at least. I get an error if I try to do this.

**Edit:** My question is: Why does this happen?

Comment: So what is your question?  An internal compiler error is not the same thing as a compiler crash, but still may be worth reporting to Microsoft.

Comment: If the compiler crashes, then that is a bug in the compiler, regardless of the code you passed to it. The compiler should never crash. Please report the bug to your compiler vendor so that they may fix it.

Comment: "Why does this happen?" Because there is a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @aschepler tnx. wasn't aware of that. I changed the title and added my question. I never have had these before so I wasn't aware that this just means it's caused by a bug in the compiler. I'll report it to MS

Comment: I would like to mention that your `typedef struct` delcarations are not really necessary. Such constructs aren't common in C++ and maybe they are the cause of compiler error. Try replacing them with simple declarations like `struct Recipe{`.

Comment: @VTT Ah. You're right. I thought that I needed to write `struct Recipe` all over the place and the typedefs were preventing this but apparently I don't need to add the `struct` keyword everywhere I use the type. I think this is a habit I've built up during my C projects. And also it apparently doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a constructor to GoodRatio seems to solve the problem:

```
GoodRatio(unsigned short goodType = {}, unsigned short units = {}) :
goodType{ goodType }, units{ units } {}
```

I have also sent feedback to microsoft.